# Como verificar parâmetros de rotas no Laravel e aceitas só parâmetros específicos?

Tags: laravel, route, where

Gostaria de saber como posso criar uma função que valida o parâmetro recebido de uma rota no `Laravel`, por exemplo, tenha uma rota:

```
Route::get('fotos/{user_id}');
```

onde só pode ter acesso os usuários onde o `user_id` for igual ao id do usuário logado.

Em uma pesquisa rápida vi que o laravel tem *`Regular Expression Constraints`* 
que funciona

```
Route::get('user/{name}', function ($name) {
    //
})->where('name', '[A-Za-z]+');`
```

e *`Route Service Provider`*, gostaria de saber como posso criar funções de validação e qual a melhor maneira de fazer algo desse tipo.

Comment: a técnica é `middleware`. [https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/middleware)

Comment: eu consigo juntar o middleware e o Service Provider? queria que toda rota que recebe um mesmo parâmetro fizesse uma validação, exemplo toda rota que receba o user_id tenha a mesma validação do id.

Comment: Ai tem um outra técnica `Route::group` coloque todas as rotas dentro dela, que tem essa lógica, e o middleware para elas no `group`. ou seja, `middleware` e `Route::group`

Comment: Esse link para `middleware` com `Route::group` => https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/middleware#middleware-groups

Answer (score 3):

De maneira alguma essa será a melhor solução neste caso.

Para isso podes colocar a verificação no controller, ou de uma forma simples na route como mencionas na pergunta:

```
Route::get('/fotos/{user_id}', function() {
    if(Auth::user()->id != request()->user_id) {
        // não é... redirecionar sujeito
    }
    // é o utilizador login, continuar lógica, buscar as fotos do utilizador com este id
});
```

**Mas atenção**:

Aconcelho vivamente a usares middleware para isto, e laravel já tem um por default:

> /app/Http/Middleware/RedirectIfAuthenticated.php

Ou seja, partindo do princípio que está tudo bem com o teu sistema de autenticação, e se só o utilizador login é que pode aceder a essa rota ("... os usuários onde o user_id for igual ao id do usuário logado."), podes/deves fazer:

```
Route::get('/fotos/user', function() {
    // se isto for executado é porque o utilizador está login
    $id_user = Auth::user()->id;
    // continuar lógica, buscar as fotos do utilizador com este id
})->middleware('auth'); // auth é o alias para o middleware descrito em cima, RedirectIfAuthenticated
```

[DOCS](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/middleware)

Reparei em comentários na pergunta (estes detalhes deveriam estar na pergunta em si), que queres fazer com que um conjunto de rotas tenham o mesmo processamento, `auth` neste caso, então podes agrupa-las (muito bem dito pelo @Virgilio Novic) no mesmo middleware, neste caso todas as rotas do grupo vão ser processadas pelo middleware `auth`:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function() {

    Route::get('/fotos/user', function() {
        // se isto for executado é porque o utilizador está login
        $id_user = Auth::user()->id;
        // continuar lógica, buscar as fotos do utilizador com este id
    });

    Route::get('/perfil/user', function() {
        // se isto for executado é porque o utilizador está login
    });

});
```

[DOCS](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/middleware#middleware-groups)